# Doubt regarding wave equation

Tags: optics, waves

We know that a solution of the wave equation can be written as $Y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$ where the letters have their usual meanings. But what does "$kx$" represent in this equation? I mean $kx$ together and not $k$ and $x$ individually?

Comment: It's good practice to assume people that read your question are not familiar with your notation. For this particular case most people would know that $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $k$ is the wavenumber and you can get away with saying the letters have their usual meanings but don't underestimate the wildly different notations that are used in physics

Answer (score 2):

$kx$ is a dimensionless quantity; the quantity $\omega t-kx$ is what we call phase of the wave and this quantity is basically angle measured in radians. So physically $kx$ should also represent angle in radians.

Comment: Please don’t use unicode in answer! It's not visible to everyone (including me) write like this - `$kx$`

Answer (score 1):

Good question! Best way to see this is to try it out for yourself! Plug it into a graphical calculator and see what happens when you change the values. For example desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator?lang=nl

It has sliders so you can really see what happens.

A hint is to look at it like this:
One number says how many cycles per unit distance there are
The other says distance

So combined they give: ..

Answer (score 0):

KX is what determines how "stretched the wave is" set t=0 for the moment.
let's say k = 0, then 1  wave length is x: 0-> 2$\pi $ as the quantity "kx" needs to go from 0 to 2pi.

if k=2, then for 1 full wave length, The quantity "kx" must go from  0 to 2pi

Meaning x now goes from 0 to pi, as when x = pi, the quantity kx, is 2pi ( meaning the cos function goes through 1 wavelength spacialy)

Now k Is defined as $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} $Thus, When when X By DEFINITION is $\lambda$ the quantity kx, reduces to $2\pi$.Meaning over a distance $\lambda$ your cos function has gone through a full wavelength spacialy.

Then obviously -$\omega $t is just a simple translation

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the wave at a given time, say t = 0 for simplicity. So a plot of y vs. x is a snapshot of the wave at that time, y = -Asin(kx).

kx = 2$\pi$x/$\lambda$, so apart from the factor of 2$\pi$, kx is a measure of the number of wavelengths in the distance x. The 2$\pi$ converts this number to a phase in radians. So for example if x=$\lambda$, this corresponds to 2$\pi$ radians which is one full cycle. For general x and t, the phase is determined by the quantity ($\omega$t - kx).